# Angular2 - Service member subscription

Tags: angular, typescript

Alright, so I know this has been asked many times - I've read many answers, and the docs, but for whatever reason this just isn't flying. I'd like to at least validate I'm not missing something.

Two Components, One Service, both Components need to interact with the Service, and one of the Components needs to react when a member of the Service changes.

Got a service with a BehaviorObject containing a domain object

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    addedMyObject:Subject<MyObject> = new BehaviorSubject();

    constructor(private http:Http) {}

    getAndAddMyObject(objectId:string) {
        this.getMyObject(objectId) // pretend this method exists
            .subscribe((o) => {
                this.addedMyObject.next(w);
            });
    }
}
```

Have one component listening to changes on the Service's BehaviorObject

```
export class MyFirstComponent() implements OnInit {

    constructor(private myService : MyService) {}

    ngOnInit() : void {
        this.myService.addedMyObject
            .subscribe((o) => {
                console.log("Incoming object, add to a list or something");
            })
    }
}
```

Have a second component calling the Service to make changes

```
export class MySecondComponent() {

    constructor(private myService : MyService) {}

    addSelectedObjectToSomething(objectId) {
        this.myService.getAndAddMyObject(objectId);
    }
}
```

And somehow, MyFirstComponent's subscription is not firing. It's kinda driving me nuts. What the heckers?

Comment: Can you certify with a `console.log` that `this.addedMyObject.next(w)` is executed? Also, can you check if it is executed before you subscribe to the service in `MyFirstComponent`?

Comment: I can certify both of those things, yes.

Comment: Code looks ok to me. I don't think this is the issue but worth a shot. next() on a observable is deprecated, try using emit

Comment: For the second question of my first comment, I assume that you certify that it is not the case. :-) Can you also certify that the service has only one provider in your application? A service having several providers, and not being a singleton, is a very common source of trouble.

Comment: As a follow up to my last comment: if each component has it own provider for the service, replace them with a single provider in the module.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of typings errors in your code so i cannot really tell you what to fix but i tried that in local and it works:

**Service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    addedMyObject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

    getAndAddMyObject(objectId: string) {
        this.getMyObject(objectId).subscribe(o => {
            this.addedMyObject.next(o);
        });
    }

    getMyObject(id: string): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.of({key: 'value'});
    }
}
```

**Component 1:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'first',
    template: `
        Hi
    `,
})
export class MyFirstComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.myService.addedMyObject.subscribe(o => {
            console.log("Incoming object, add to a list or something", o);
        })
    }
}
```

**Component 2:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'second',
    template: `
        <button (click)="addSelectedObjectToSomething(1)">Add</button>
    `,
})
export class MySecondComponent {

    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

    addSelectedObjectToSomething(objectId) {
        this.myService.getAndAddMyObject(objectId);
    }
}
```

When i click on the button of the second component i see the log with the correct object displayed.